# How does the trainable projection layer used in PRADO and pQRNN work?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

Trainable projection layers are said to be a very powerful thing but after reading:

- https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/D19-1506.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.08890.pdf

I don't understand how it works. So how does the trainable projection layer used in PRADO and pQRNN work?

Answer (score 0):

The key idea in both the papers are word embeddings are replaced by trainable activations that are computed using a nueral network. The network (referred to as bottleneck layer) takes word projections as input. The parameters of this network is shared across tokens. This results in a trainable token representation. The projection itself is not trainable, but the representation derived from projection is trainable. Hope that clarifies.